# SQL Server ROW_NUMBER behavior

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
       a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.TeacherID) AS RowNum 
    FROM 
       SelectAll a  
    LEFT JOIN 
       mp_Ratings r ON a.TeacherID = r.TeacherID 
    GROUP BY 
       a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID
) AS TeacherInfo 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 50
```

and it works fine. Now, If I want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
       a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.TeacherID) AS RowNum 
    FROM 
       SelectAll a  
    LEFT JOIN 
       mp_Ratings r ON a.TeacherID = r.TeacherID 
    GROUP BY 
       a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID
) AS TeacherInfo 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 50 AND UniversityID = 2
```

I get nothing because the `UniversityID = 2` begins around row number **2991**. I would like to be able to reset the `Row_Number` with every different `UniversityID`.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TeacherID) AS RowNum  
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID 
    FROM 
        SelectAll a  
    LEFT JOIN 
        mp_Ratings r ON a.TeacherID = r.TeacherID 
    GROUP BY 
        a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID
) AS TeacherInfo 
WHERE UniversityID = 2
```

which brings new set of `row_numbers` for every search, but if I try to use `RowNum` alias as such:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TeacherID) AS RowNum  
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID 
    FROM 
        SelectAll a  
    LEFT JOIN 
        mp_Ratings r ON a.TeacherID = r.TeacherID 
    GROUP BY 
        a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID
) AS TeacherInfo 
WHERE UniversityID = 2 
  AND RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

I get

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'RowNum'.

What is wrong with my select? Why can't I access the `RowNum` alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to move the `WHERE` clause to the inner query.

```
SELECT TeacherID, UniversityID, RowNum FROM
(
    SELECT a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (ORDER BY a.TeacherID) AS RowNum FROM SelectAll a
     LEFT JOIN mp_Ratings r 
     ON a.TeacherID = r.TeacherID 
     WHERE UniversityID = 2
     GROUP BY a.TeacherID, a.UniversityID
) as TeacherInfo WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 50;
```

You can't access the `RowNum` alias in the outer version of the query because the alias doesn't exist yet. `SELECT` is parsed second-last, before `ORDER BY`. `WHERE` is processed before `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks, I already had a WHERE clause inside the inner select, but I did not notice I also had an OR clause which was causing the select to bring UniversityID=1 and 2 (because of the OR).

Answer (score 1):

Use partition on `row_number`:

```
row_number() over(partition by UniversityID, order by teacherid)
```